AWS MediaConvert generating double length video
I am new to aws media convert. I am trying to convert the video but the final output video becomes double the length from the original one. for example if I have a video 30 seconds long, it will create 60 seconds long final video. Below is my son.
{
  "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:us-west-2:730335xxxxx:queues/Default",
  "UserMetadata": {},
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::73033541xxxx:role/service-role/MediaConvert_Default_Role",
  "Settings": {
    "TimecodeConfig": {
      "Source": "ZEROBASED"
    },
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "DASH ISO",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MPD"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "MaxBitrate": 3500000,
                  "RateControlMode": "QVBR",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "TRANSITION_DETECTION"
                }
              }
            },
            "NameModifier": "_output1"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "DASH_ISO_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "DashIsoGroupSettings": {
            "SegmentLength": 30,
            "Destination": "s3://tutorial/video/",
            "FragmentLength": 2,
            "SegmentControl": "SINGLE_FILE"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "FollowSource": 1,
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT"
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {},
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://tutorial/video/11 - video.mp4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "BillingTagsSource": "JOB",
  "AccelerationSettings": {
    "Mode": "DISABLED"
  },
  "StatusUpdateInterval": "SECONDS_60",
  "Priority": 0
}

Please help

That's odd.  There are no other recent reports of this, so it's likely to be an issue with either your job configuration OR in your source file, or a combination of the two when 'follow source' is used in place of explicit output settings.
This mp4 source file may have a variable frame rate and/or ELST exclusion pointers.  If you have a MediaConvert job ID,  AWS Premium Support can pull the internal logs for that job and dive deeper. The free Mediainfo utility can tell you if the source file is a variable-frame-rate file.
Some initial suggestions:
• The most common reason for a time-scaled output is some misalignment between GOP size, frame rate, segment length and fragment time. This can happen when 'follow source' is used to infer transcode parameters and the source has some unusual formatting.
Suggestions:
• Try your current job settings with a different mp4 source and see if time dilation still results.
• Update job settings to use an explicit output frame rate and GOP.
• If the troubled source is variable frame rate, try standardizing the framerate first with a video pre-processing utility
